# How can I use Application Recovery and Restart in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

MSDN [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc948909%28VS.85%29.aspx) that "ARR is designed for C and C++ developers." After googling around for a while, I could not find any Delphi example for ARR. Is it possible to use ARR in a Delphi application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but as far as there are headers for it, it should work. For implementing it, you can get the [`JEDI API Headers`](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/jedi-api-headers/) that contains [`JwaAppRecovery.pas`](http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaAppRecovery.pas?view=markup) unit, covering the Application Recovery and Restart API.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a regular Windows C-style API. A quick Google search reveals that [InnoSetup supports it](http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm), so there should be your Delphi source code example, too.